# loading a external content so that searchable by Google for SEO purposes

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, seo

I'm working on a project where we'd like to load external content onto a customers site. The main requirements are that we'd like the customer to have as simple of an include as possible (like a one-line link similar to Doubleclick) and would preferably not have to be involved in any server-side language. The two proposed ways of doing this were an iframe or loading a javascript file that document.write's out the content.

We looked more at the latter since it seemed to produce more reliable legibility and simplicity for the end user - a single line of Javascript. We have been hit with the reality that this will be indexed unpredictably by Google. I have read most of the posts on this topic regarding javascript and indexing (for example http://www.seroundtable.com/google-ajax-execute-15169.html, https://twitter.com/mattcutts/status/131425949597179904). Currenlty we have (for example):

```
<html>
<body>
  <div class='main-container'>
    <script src='http://www.other.com/page.js'></script>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and

```
// at http://www.other.com/page.js
document.write('blue fish and green grass');
```

but it looks like google indexes this type of content only sometimes based upon 'Fetch As Google' used in Google's webmaster tools. Since it does sometimes work, I know it's possible for this indexing to be ok. More specifically, if we isolate our content to something like the above and remove extraneous content, it will index it each time (as opposed to the EXACT SAME Javascript in a regular customer html page).  If we have our content in a customer's html file it doesn't seem to get indexed.

What would be a better option to ensure that Google has indexed the content (remote isn't any better)? Ideas I have tried / come across would be to load a remote file in for example PHP, something like:

```
echo file_get_contents('http://www.other.com/page');
```

This is obviously blocking but possibly not a deal-breaker.

Given the above requirements, would there be any other solution?

thx

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem and I've created a JS plugin that you can use to solve this.

Url: https://github.com/kubrickology/Logical-escaped_fragment

Make sure to use the: `__init()` function instead of standard DOM ready functions and you know for sure that Google is able to index.